# DOCX to HTML with PHPword

Tags: phpword

I've currently got

```
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($word_file);
$htmlWriter = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\HTML($phpWord);
```

Where $word_file is the location of the word document.  What I want to do is output the HTML to the screen, not save it to a file.  I can't seem to find any documentation on anything except htmlWriter->save();  My question is, how would I simply output the HTML vs Saving it to a file?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I figured it out.  I need to use $htmlWriter->getContent();

Hope this helps someone else!